# Similar concept for "nilpotent" matrix but gives the identity and not 0?

Tags: matrices, permutations, nilpotence

Is there a term for a square matrix $E$ such that $E^k=I$ for some positive integer $k$?
To provide context: I was experimenting with permutation matrices and discovered that they satisfy the interesting property above. I have not proved/disproved this claim, I am looking for some hints and suspect that it has a nice name. Initially I thought it would be called "unipotent" (like how "nilpotent" is defined) but that's not it.

Comment: You are asking for a hint why permutation matrices satisfy the property that there always exists some positive integer $k$ such that $E^k=I$?  This follows from that the permutation matrix is a representation of the permutation itself, and that the permutation can be thought of as residing in the finite group $S_n$.  As for hints on how to continue the proof, recall that $S_n$ has only finitely many elements and that permutations are closed under composition.

Comment: As far as what to call the property., idempotent seems close, but that term is in use to describe a matrix $E$ such that $E^2 = E$.  I don't know that I've heard a specific term to describe what you are after.  Note that permutation matrices are not the only matrices with this property.  Off the top of my head, rotation matrices have this as well, as well as combinations of these.  One can also prove that a matrix with the property you are talking about must be diagonalizable, and is a common exercise.

Comment: @JMoravitz Your example on rotation is immediately clear to me and I can also relate it to consecutive multiplication of the complex kth-root of unity. 'Idempotent' seems close, but such matrices are all singular (except the identity matrix), while the matrices defined above are invertible. On the topic of permutation, I have a related question: Can we say if $k$ is the least/greatest number of permutations required to sort a list of numbers in ascending order? Or is k, as defined above, relevant at all in sorting a list?

Comment: I don't follow your most recent question, but given a permutation matrix $A$ the smallest positive $k$ such that $A^k = I$ is called the [order of the permutation](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-order-of-a-permutation) and a well known theorem about the order of a permutation is that it is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles in the permutations disjoint cyclic decomposition.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree that my question is not very clear since I merely translated it from my MATLAB code for counting the repeated permutations until the original list (sorted) is return. The link you attached answers my question precisely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k = 2$ the term is involutory matrix - a matrix that is its own inverse. In general matrices such that that a power of them is the identity are called matrices of finite order.

You can think about it this way - the repeated application of such a matrix to a vector must ultimately give same the vector back since repeated applications eventually lead to multiplying by the identity. That means that for a matrix where $E^k = I$ all of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ must satisfy $\lambda_i^k =1$. I believe that condition defines the set of matrices with this property.

See also [Is permutation matrix the only matrix for which $A^k = A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976937/is-permutation-matrix-the-only-matrix-for-which-ak-a)